# Integral of $au^2$ where $a$ is continuous and $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Tags: continuity, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a smooth domain with bounded complement. Let $a \in C(\Omega)$ and let $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$. Suppose that $a > 0$ in $\Omega$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{\vert x \vert \rightarrow \infty} = \alpha > 0$.

> Is the following integral: $$I = \int_{\Omega} a u^2 \, dx$$ finite ?

Since $a$ is not necessarily continuous up to the boundary, bad things can happen on $\partial \Omega$. For example, the function
$$a(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{\vert x \vert^2 - 1}$$
equals $\infty$ on $\partial \Omega$ where $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^N \setminus B(0;1)$.

But $u$ vanishes—in the sense of traces—on $\partial \Omega$. Is that enough to guarantee that $I < \infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $u\in W^{1,2}_0$ gives a tiny amount of information on how it vanishes near the boundary. Thus, in order to get $\int au^2<\infty$ you need to know a lot about  how $a$ can blow up. Absent such information, counterexamples are abundant: $$a(x)=1+\frac{1}{(|x|^2-1)^3}, \quad u(x)=(|x|-1)\exp(-|x|^2)$$

Comment: Thanks. We could require $a$ to be bounded on $\Omega$, but this is perhaps a little bit extreme. Or require $a \in L^{\frac{N}{2}}(\Omega)$, since by the Sobolev imbedding $u \in L^{2^*}(\Omega)$.